# Why is a Null Pointer in C equal to another Null Pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Like consider I declare two pointers NULL. Then if I compare them, the result is true. But if we consider NULL to be "nothing" then how can we say that two "nothings" are equal? Is that for some specific reason?   Any help appreciated. :)

Comment: Because there's only _the_ null pointer.

Comment: Consider I declare two ints to be `5`. If I compare them, they're equal. The same idea applies to pointers.

Comment: "Why" questions are hard to answer on SO.  The answer "because the standard says so" is unsatisfying, and the question "why does the standard say that?" requires a psychoanalysis of the personalities and goals of all standards authors, and an understanding of the process by which the standard is produced.

Comment: Instead, try asking "what" questions that have answers. "What line of the specification defines null pointers to be equal?" is a question that has an answer. "What have members of the standards committee said publically about that design choice?" is a question that has an answer. "What design processes could lead a standards team to produce an "isnan" function for doubles but not an "isnull" function for pointers?" is a question that requires an *opinion*, but at least it has an *answer*.  **Ask a more clear question.**

Comment: @EricLippert : Okay. I got it. New to SO. :)

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this. In fact I think it is a good question. Cf. NaN of floating point.

Comment: @Bathsheba: And what happens when you try to compare two NaNs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you point pointer to NULL then it means that it is pointing to the memory address `0x0`.

Consider following example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *p = NULL;
..
..
```

Here, *p is pointing to `NULL`. If we check in `gdb` then we will get following,

```
(gdb) p p
$1 = 0x0
```

`0x0` is the address of `NULL` value i.e. 0. You cannot access `0x0` memory address.

```
(gdb) p *p
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

If you try to access memory address `0x0` then program will be crashed by saying `segmentation fault`

Now if you compare two pointers which are pointing to memory address `0x0` i.e. `NULL` then it will be same only as the `NULL` value is `0` by default

Answer (score 7):

In C, two null pointers of any type are guaranteed to compare equal. The macro `NULL` is defined as **an implementation-defined null pointer constant**, which in `C99` can be portably expressed as the integer value 0 converted implicitly or explicitly to the type `void *` .